# Upload pdf base64 to Amazon S3 using Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda

I am new to S3 lambda, I created a sample lambda function and added to api gateway and now I am able to invoke the lambda fucntion from postman. I need to send the json input with pdf base64 as below to lambda function.

```
{
  "documents": [
    {
      "documentBase64": "SGVsbG8=....",
      "documentId": "11",
      "fileExtension": "pdf",
      "name": "sample",
      "order": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

In s3 lambda function, I need to read this input and upload it as pdf.
How can I do this? lambda function implementation can be node js or pyhthon or java.
Appreciate your quick help.

Thank You,
Sree

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about details of AWS lambda service and its requirements, but you can load a base64 object in python like this:

```
import io

document_base64 = ...

byte_obj = io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(document_base64))
```

I assume you cannot write to file on lambda service, but you can do this in other places that you can write to disk:

```
with open('filename.pdb', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(base64.b64decode(document_base64))
```

Comment: Thank you for quick input. Now my input contains,                                        `{ "documents": [ {
"documentId": "11",
"fileExtension": "pdf",
"name": "sample",
"body": "<?xml ...<DocInformation><Documents><Document>SGVsbG8=....",
} ] }`                                                                                                                  
  So how can I get the body XML base64 payload in the input json payload? Once I get that base64 then I can try your code.                                                                                        
Thank you!!

Comment: @sridb so the value of `body` is base64 encoded too? You can use `base64` library there too, like how it's used in the response. `base64.b64.decode(<value-of-body>)` decodes the value and you get your xml text.

Comment: the <document> is base64 not the entire body. so i need to read the body from json,parse the xml, get the <document> base64 code. I did this,

Comment: jstr = json.dumps(event)                                                                                                                                     y = json.loads(jstr)                                                                                           
docuContent = y["body"]                                                                                                                                
 root = ET.fromstring(docuContent)                                                                                                
  print(root.tag). Any better idea?